# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm learning ASP.Net and attempted to create a default ASP.Net project in VS2010 for the first time using VB.Net for the programming language.

After running the ASP.Net project, a default web page was displayed in a browser window. I tried to click on the LogIn link on the displayed web page and this error is displayed:

```
The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server
```

We are using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. We also have IIS7 installed in Window7. We have SQL Server, Visual Studio 2010 and IIS7 installed on the same computer.

I'm assuming a new database needs to be created but I don't know the details on what this database looks like or if there is a script that can be run that creates it.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string for that application probably has `User Instance=true` set, which is only valid for SQL Server Express. You should remove that part from the connection string.

SQL Server 2012 no longer has user instances, instead opting for LocalDB.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I found and ran aspnet_regsql.exe and it created a database called aspnetdb. I started up Management Studio and ran the commands in you reply but it comes back with this error:     Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 The configuration option 'user instances enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen Hm, it seems that this is no longer a part of SQL Server 2012. You should just change your connection string to not use user instances.

Comment: Silly question. I just looked at the Setting tab of the project and did not find a connection string. Can you tell me the location of the connection string? Thanks.

Comment: An application can squirrel it away where ever it wants, but most commonly it is in the app.config file or the web.config file.

Comment: Found it in web.config but a different error is now displayed. Here is the error: A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen Can you post the modified connection string?

Comment: connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf" This is what it looks like now minus the User Instance=True part.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out that I needed to remove User Instance=True. After some hacking around I found the culprit to be the  AttachDBFilename= keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it.

I changed the connection string to look like this:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True;"
```

The problem was being caused by:

```
AttachDBFilename=
```

It threw me off because I was assuming VS2010 would create the correct connection string.